# Retrofti Json RecyclerView: No adapter attached;

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I put on my json data in this URL= http://api.myjson.com/bins/1fblzn

it contains location data and has 5 fields, three of them are Strings and two of them are Doubles.

I want to show it in recyclerview.

but I keep getting this error.

I searched a lot but I couldn't get an answer.

Here's my code:

**MainActivityRecyc**

```
    public class MainActivityRecyc extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivityRecyc.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Locations> data;
    private DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_recyc);
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RequestInterface requestInterface =
                JsonClient.getClient().create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = requestInterface.getJson();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call,
                                   Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                List<Locations> data = response.body().getData();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(data, R.layout.card_row, getApplicationContext()));            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }        });    }     }
```

**Locations**

```
      public class Locations {
    private String name;
    private String pname;
    private String bicycleno;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lang;
            public Locations(String name, String pname, String bicycleno,
                             Double lat, Double lang){
                this.name= name;
                this.pname= pname;
                this.bicycleno= bicycleno;
                this.lat= lat;
                this.lang= lang;
            } 
   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void  setName (String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }
    public void  setPname(String pname){
        this.pname=pname;
    }
    public String getBicycleno() {
        return bicycleno;
    }
    public void setBicycleno (String bicycleno){
        this.bicycleno=bicycleno;
    }
    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat (Double lat){
        this.lat=lat;
    }
    public Double getLang() {
        return lang;
    }
    public void setLang (Double lang){
        this.lang=lang;
    }    }
```

**RequestInterface**

```
     public interface RequestInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
    @GET("/bins/1fblzn/")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJson();
    }
```

**DataAdapter**

```
      public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<Locations> data=new ArrayList<>();
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;
    public DataAdapter(List<Locations> data ,int rowLayout, Context context){
        this.data = data;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        Locations locations= data.get(i);
        viewHolder.name.setText(data.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.pname.setText(data.get(i).getPname());
        viewHolder.bicycleno.setText(data.get(i).getBicycleno());
        viewHolder.lat.setText(data.get(i).getLat().toString());
        viewHolder.lang.setText(data.get(i).getLang().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return data.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView name,pname,bicycleno, lat, lang;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            pname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pname);
            bicycleno = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bicycleno);
            lat = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lat);
            lang = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lang);
        }   } }
```

JSONResponse

```
public class JSONResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Locations> data =new ArrayList<>();

public List<Locations> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

JsonClient

```
 public class JsonClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

Comment: What error? And what line of code does the error point at ?

Comment: @MehmetKologlu it doesn't specify any line.the problem is instead of a list of json data I get a blank screen. two error I keep seeing is  Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras and RecyclerView: No adapter attached;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `LinearLayoutManager` in your implementation, use this code instead

`DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(data, R.layout.card_row, getApplicationContext());
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(newLinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Hope this helps, Happy codding!

Comment: it didn't work. I see this line of error too: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fourth line of your `onCreate`:

`recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`

The adapter you're passing here is just `null` because you've never assigned a value to the field `private DataAdapter adapter;`. Right before the aforementioned 4th line, add code to instantiate the adapter. Since you don't have any data at that point, just pass empty data:

`adapter = new DataAdapter(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, R.layout.card_row, getApplicationContext())`

Then later when you get the data from the request, just update the data of the adapter and call `notifyDataChanged()`;

Comment: it didn't work. I see this line of error too: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras